# Why am i getting error when use concat instead of || in below query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 'THERE ARE A TOTAL OF '||COUNT(*) ||' '|| OCCUPATION
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC, OCCUPATION ASC;
```

I have used

```
SELECT CONCAT('THERE ARE A TOTAL OF ', CONCAT(COUNT(*), OCCUPATION))
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: And what dialect are you using? Tag also with specific engine, like [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server]...

Comment: why don't you use + operator ? like : select 'THERE ARE A TOTAL OF ' + count(*) + ....

Comment: @cchajar: because `+` is for adding numbers in SQL, not for concatenating strings

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
SELECT concat('THERE ARE A TOTAL OF ',COUNT(*) ,' ',OCCUPATION)
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC, OCCUPATION ASC
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT CONCAT('THERE ARE A TOTAL OF ',COUNT(*) ,' ', OCCUPATION) As aliasName
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC, OCCUPATION ASC
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.